# Dual Boot Freezing Before or After Login

Tags: dual-boot, login, lightdm, systemd-logind

I dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Windows 10. The installation of 16.04 seemed to go really well, and I've gotten everything set up the way I like, but I'm having a couple of weird bugs that are really annoying. Basically most times I try to login, it either freezes on the login screen before I can start typing, or after I enter my password and hit enter, it will just show the desktop background and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS watermark. I can move the mouse pointer around, but that's it! I have to do a hard shutdown, then start it back up. Then sometimes it will work, but usually not. Waking it from sleep on subsequent startups, it freezes at some point. This is all on a fresh installation that runs with no issues while it actually works. How can I fix this?

Edit: I cannot boot from DVD without just getting a black screen. I did some research, and tried some things, but can't seem to get it. Are the files I currently have possibly useful at all?

Edit #2:
Bear with me here, I don't know how useful this is... This is what happened when it froze on login last night, as documented in the kern.log. I have no idea what it means, but I hope someone does

```
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]: <info>  [1470103327.0831] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]: <info>  [1470103327.0832] manager: sleeping...
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]: <info>  [1470103327.0832] device (wlp4s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]: <info>  [1470103327.1160] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 10804
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]: <info>  [1470103327.1161] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> done
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.246057] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 28:c6:8e:ec:b2:7e by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]: <info>  [1470103327.1266] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]: <info>  [1470103327.1339] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273013] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273016] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273017] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273018] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273019] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273020] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273021] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273022] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273023] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273023] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273024] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
\00
```

That last part (\00) a BUNCH of times though. In red in the file. syslog was slightly more informative.

```
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]:   [1470103327.0831] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]:   [1470103327.0832] manager: sleeping...
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]:   [1470103327.0832] device (wlp4s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]:   [1470103327.1160] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 10804
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]:   [1470103327.1161] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> done
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.246057] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 28:c6:8e:ec:b2:7e by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 wpa_supplicant[3080]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=28:c6:8e:ec:b2:7e reason=3 locally_generated=1
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 whoopsie[2817]: [21:02:07] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 whoopsie[2817]: [21:02:07] offline
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]:   [1470103327.1266] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.190 on wlp4s0.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.190.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Interface wlp4s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Withdrawing address record for 2602:306:2573:89f9:70a1:bdef:8c53:de91 on wlp4s0.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address 2602:306:2573:89f9:70a1:bdef:8c53:de91.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address 2602:306:2573:89f9:e807:5cdd:f122:4b9f.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Withdrawing address record for 2602:306:2573:89f9:e807:5cdd:f122:4b9f on wlp4s0.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp4s0.IPv6 with address 2602:306:2573:89f9:e807:5cdd:f122:4b9f.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 avahi-daemon[2821]: Interface wlp4s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 whoopsie[2817]: [21:02:07] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 dnsmasq[3594]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 NetworkManager[2913]:   [1470103327.1339] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273013] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273016] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273017] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273018] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273019] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273020] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273021] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273022] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273023] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273023] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 kernel: [19513.273024] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 whoopsie[2817]: [21:02:07] Cannot reach: DAISYUBUNTULINK
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 dbus[2887]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 dbus[2887]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp4s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp4s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug  1 21:02:07 XPS-8700 wpa_supplicant[3080]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp4s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug  1 21:02:08 XPS-8700 gnome-session[3563]: (deja-dup-monitor:4616): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 249 was not found when attempting to remove it
Aug  1 21:02:08 XPS-8700 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug  1 21:02:08 XPS-8700 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug  1 21:02:08 XPS-8700 systemd-sleep[11156]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Aug  1 21:02:08 XPS-8700 systemd-sleep[11158]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Aug  1 21:02:08 XPS-8700 systemd-sleep[11156]: Suspending system...
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

Where I said DAISYUBUNTULINK is same as other links, it just told me I couldn't post any more links.

Comment: In general this is hardware related. If the lockup is random it also most times is memory. 1st advice: Boot from a live dvd and look at contents of `/var/log/` specifically `boot.log` and `syslog` and `kern.log` with `tail -n 100 {logfile}` and check for errors. If you find anything add it into the question.

Comment: I forgot to mention: It USUALLY does not freeze up when I hit suspend. Also, on original login, it really helps if I hit keys on the keyboard. Doesn't always work, but does sometimes, and it seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

Rinzwind, thank you! You put me down the right path, and I was much better able to research the problem after you told me about the logs. I found many others with my problem, and I seem to have fixed it by upgrading to Linux kernel 4.4.8-040408-generic. Apparently 4.4.0 has serious issues with hardware similar to mine. Thanks again.